# php class namespace issue

Tags: php, class

i found in php documentation this part that I need but getting issues
[PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

check example 3

my code

```
namespace Test;
class Test{
    public function __construct() {
        echo 1;

    }
}

use Test\Test as Test;
$a = 'Test';
new $a;
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Test' not found in

ps. when I create with `new Test` then everything works OK

version PHP 7.0.4

Comment: Problem is string. If you do new Test...test will be referenced by Test\Test but if you do 'Test' It not be referenced and throw that error.

Comment: but in documentation is string as well or I am missing something?

Comment: missing.. doc says 'instantiates object of class Another' not previous class. So your error class Test is missing because you want new Test and NOT class Test\Test. Doc is right

Comment: if you do fqdn $a = 'Test\Test' it will be ok.

Comment: this works, thanks

Comment: np, you are welcome :)